# CTRL+D is not working in vs code copy similar code

Tags: performance, visual-studio-code

Previous in I have used ctr+d for duplicating the code many times, but when I switched to desktop and installed vs code and all the necessary extensions for my react project. And now this CTRL+D keyboard shortcut is not working. Can any help me to solve this issue

Comment: Yeah it worked for me when I tried changing shortcuts , I used ctrl+d for copying line down.

Answer (score 11):

I recently met this issue too. I found a solution, see this: https://linuxpip.org/duplicate-lines-vscode/.
The main step are:

1. File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts.
2. type "copy line",then you will see the related shortcuts.
3. remember the new shortcut(e.g. Shift + Alt + Down) or modify the shortcut to ctrl + D.

Answer (score 3):

Similar issue for Windows 10, resolved using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

shift + alt + arrow-down works for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a VS Code extension causing the ctrl + ... binds not to work. It was "Vim emulation". Try isolating the issue by uninstalling the extensions until you find which one.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me. The cause was the Notepad++ extension. I went to Settings->Keyboard Shortcuts and entered "CTRL+D", and then I saw that Notepad++ and the system claimed that shortcut. All I had to do to fix it was delete the shortcut I didn't want.

Comment: Settings in Windows OS? If so, which version?

Comment: No. Settings are in VS Code. Works on Windows 10.